# In an election there are 1080 votes, 5 electoral candidates but only 3 available seats. Calculate minimum number of votes needed to guarantee a seat.

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, algebra-precalculus, percentages

I've received this grade school math problem but unfortunately algebra cannot be used. I am somewhat stumped and not convinced with my own answers. Here goes:

At a grade school election, there were 1080 voters. 5 students are running to be officers however there are only 3 seats available. What is the minimum number of votes needed to guarantee a seat?

Assume that everyone votes and that each person can only vote once. I also think the voting system might be culturally different, so the way it works here is that the 3 people with the highest votes are automatically officers. 
Basically the 1080 votes are spread over the 5 candidates, only the highest 3 are guaranteed positions.

I would appreciate both algebraic and non-algebraic answers.

Thank you very much!

Comment: What is your own answer?

Comment: What voting system is applied?

Comment: @celtschk plurality I suppose. It's an elementary math problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>This is a trick question, if I understand it correctly.  You must get at least $1$ vote.  Two other candidates each get no votes, and the remaining two candidates split the other $1079$ votes between them.</s>

If you get a quarter of the votes, it's not possible for three people to get more votes than you, because that would add up to more than four quarters, but since $1080$ is divisible by $4$ the selection could end in a four-way tie.  The answe therefore is $${1080\over4}+1=271$$

Comment: Hello! Thank you for this answer! I've recently updated the question with the assumption that everyone has to vote and can only vote once, it also looks like 2 people getting zero votes is not a possibility. There is an answer to the problem but it is unfortunately not yet available to me.

Comment: @user652360 Are you assuming everyone votes for himself?  That isn't stated in the problem.  If you want to assume that, then the minimum is $2$.

Comment: I think the question is asking 'How many votes will *guarantee* a seat'

Comment: @DanielMathias That makes a lot more sense than my reading.

Comment: Assuming each candidate is also a voter and will vote for self, $270$ votes will secure a seat. The remaining $810$ votes being distributed among four candidates with each getting at least one vote means at least two candidates will have fewer than $270$ votes.

Comment: @DanielMathias Yes, that's true, but the assumption that everyone votes for himself is not given.

Comment: 271 was the answer provided in the key. Thank you very much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming draws are allowed (in which case the higher index is then prefered), we have that
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 \le x_{\,1}  \le x_{\,2}  \le x_{\,3}  \le x_{\,4}  \le x_5  \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,1}  + x_{\,2}  + x_{\,3}  + x_{\,4}  + x_5  = n \hfill \cr}  \right.
$$

Clearly the minimum for $x_3$ will occur when $x_1=x_2=0$, in which case
$1$ vote (or also none, according to the preference rule) for $x_3$ is sufficient.

The challenge comes when $x_2$ get "many" votes.
The maximum he can reach without succeeding is when
$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  0 = x_{\,1}  \hfill \cr 
  x_{\,2}  \le x_{\,3}  \le x_{\,4}  \le x_5  \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \,\quad \left\lfloor {n/4} \right\rfloor  = x_{\,2}  \le x_{\,3} 
$$

So the answer is that $x_3$ shall get minimum  $\left\lfloor {n/4} \right\rfloor$ votes to be sure of being elected.